# Open and read a file in firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

What is wrong in this code ? I don't understend, if I remove the "Try" my app dont open, and if don't remove always appear "need login" ...

```
procedure TF_login.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
 var
      Result: Integer;
      TextFile: TStringList;
      VarArquivo: string;
      text: string;
      dataI, dataF : string;
begin
  TextFile := TStringList.Create;
  VarArquivo := System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + 'Limit.txt';
  try
    TextFile.LoadFromFile(VarArquivo);

    text := TextFile.Text;
//    ShowMessage(TextFile.Text); // there is the text
//    ShowMessage(text); // there is the text

    dataI := FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy', Now);
    dataF := FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy', StrToDate(text));

    Result := CompareDate(StrToDate(dataI), StrToDate(dataF));
    ShowMessage(dataF +' data f');
    ShowMessage(dataI +' data I');
    if ( Result = LessThanValue ) then
    begin
      ShowMessage('data F low');
    end
    else
    begin
      ShowMessage('data F high');
      F_inicio.Show;
    end;

    FreeAndNil(TextFile);
  except on E:
    Exception do ShowMessage('An error happened!' + sLineBreak + '[' + 
                               E.ClassName + '] ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

> The error : [EConvertError] '09/11/2019' is not a valid date

to create the file, i do:

```
procedure TF_login.btn_entrarClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  data : tdatetime;
  Resposta, data_s: string;
begin
   PathFile := System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath;
   NameFile := 'Limit.txt';
   data := Now; //data actual
   data := IncMonth(data, 2);
   data_s := FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy', data);
   TFile.WriteAllText(TPath.Combine(PathFile, NameFile), data_s );
   F_inicio.Show;
end;
```

The file exists, because the first (and second) ShowMessage (what is commented) show me the "09/11/19" but the third and fourth not appear to me...

OBS: Delphi 10.3 (RIO), Plataform: Android

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199099/discussion-on-question-by-user3602803-open-and-read-a-file-in-firemonkey).

Comment: Use the debugger to find out exactly where your code fails. At the moment we can see that an exception is raised, but you swallow it, along with all the information it provides.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of things that you should change in your code:

```
procedure TF_login.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
 var
      TextFile: TStringList;
      VarArquivo: string;
      text: string;
      dataI, dataF : string;
begin
  // If an exception (unlikely, but on principle) happens in your VarArquivo
  // assignment, then the original version will leak the allocated TStringList.
  // Always place the TRY right after allocation of a memory block. That way
  // you ensure that the FINALLY block will always release the allocated
  // memory. Also, always include a FINALLY block to release the memory. Don't
  // count on your code to reach the FreeAndNIL code (it doesn't in this
  // instance, as you can see) to make sure that you actually release the
  // memory.
  VarArquivo := System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + 'Limit.txt';
  TextFile := TStringList.Create;
  try // - except
    try // - finally
      TextFile.LoadFromFile(VarArquivo);

      text := TextFile.Text;
  //    ShowMessage(TextFile.Text); // there is the text
  //    ShowMessage(text); // there is the text

      dataI := FormatDateTime('yyyy/mm/dd', Date);
      dataF := FormatDateTime('yyyy/mm/dd', StrToDate(text));
      ShowMessage(dataF +' data f');
      ShowMessage(dataI +' data I');
      if ( dataF < dataI ) then
      begin
        ShowMessage('data F low');
      end
      else
      begin
        ShowMessage('data F high');
        F_inicio.Show;
      end;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(TextFile);
    end
  except
    // NEVER just "eat" an exception. Especially not while developing the
    // application.
    // Always either log the exception or show it to the user.
    on E:Exception do ShowMessage('Exception '+E.ClassName+': '+E.Message+#13#10+
                                  'need login');
  end;
end;
```

Now - if you do this, what exception and error message is shown. This is needed in order to properly diagnose the error. Perhaps you can even figure it out for yourself when you see what exactly goes wrong...

Comment: Thanks, but already talking-me about this, and i changed the code, the error is: 
  `  "[EConvertError] '09/11/2019' is not a valid date "`

Comment: `Result := CompareDate(StrToDate(dataI), StrToDate(dataF)); `
the line of code that makes the comparison

Comment: @user3602803: And there you have it (as expected). The string '09/11/2019' is not a valid date as specified in the default date format for the machine it is running on. Where does this date come from? Is it DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY format? Is it always the same format? If so, you can supply an extra parameter to the date conversion functions that tells the format used in the string instead of relying on the machine you're running on having the same date format as the machine producing the string in the first place...

Comment: Finally, I found out what the error was, the "text" variable when catch the text file, a line break was inserted, something unnoticeable because there was nothing beyond the date.
I inserted text := copy(text, 1, 10) in my code, this works :)

Comment: @user3602803 I would probably use text := TextFile.Text.Trim instead of assuming that the line is 10 characters long.